# Who were actually the bureau guys in The Adjustment Bureau?

Tags: the-adjustment-bureau

Today I watched [The Adjustment Bureau](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1385826/) and found it very interesting. But the one thing this movie didn't explained is the species of the members of the bureau. What are they? Aliens changing our fate? Super-humans created by Government to control lives of people? Humans from future changing our history as shown in [Fringe](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1119644/)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### FILM :

The [film](http://screenplayexplorer.com/wp-content/scripts/The_Adjustment_Bureau.pdf) isn't very enlightening relating to the nature of the Adjustment Bureau. The most pertinent quote is that

> ***"We're the people who make sure things happen according to the Plan."***.

Simply put, there's a (*divine?*) plan and they're in charge of making sure it happens.

While the implication is that the proctors are in fact **angels** (or at least agents of a *god-like* Chairman), the Director George Nolfi left the answer to that question [deliberately vague](http://io9.com/5775887/the-adjustment-bureaus-director-explains-the-men-who-rule-your-fate);

> "For me, it's not an explicitly religious movie in any way. It is a
>   movie that takes us into the territory that any religion or big
>   philosophical question has to deal with. This issue of, How much do
>   your choices matter, and how much is your life laid out for you by
>   larger issues? **Whether you want to view those things as a divine plan
>   or not. It's not my goal, in the movie, to do anything other than tell
>   a fun story, and hopefully leave people with some questions when they
>   walk out of the theater.** And different people will take those
>   questions in different directions."

---

### SHORT STORY:

In the [short story](http://en.wikisource.org/wiki/Adjustment_Team) by Philip K Dick, it's rather more clear that the Adjustment Bureau are using **advanced technology and time travel** to alter the time-stream to a more favourable and less violent outcome. Their plan seems to be to foster the creation of a **society of scientists** that may or may not represent the earliest incarnation of the Bureau...

> "The circle will widen. Other scientists on both sides will be drawn
>   in. A society will be founded. More and more educated men will
>   transfer an increasing amount of time to this international society.
>   Purely national research will suffer a slight but extremely critical
>   eclipse. The war tension will somewhat wane"

### The short answer is that there's no answer. It's been deliberately left vague by the original author.

Comment: But at least they must have explained why the bureau wants everything according to plan? And who actually created that plan? I like these kinds of movies that deliberately leave the ending vague, like Nolan's Inception. But this movie left its viewers unsatisfied. I love this movie because of the new concept but I am feeling like I've not watched it completely.

Comment: In the book, it was to reduce global tension and help to create a society of scientists. In the film they seem to be shepherding him toward becoming President.

Comment: At one point, as I recall, Harry is asked point-blank if they are angels. (On the boat, I believe)  His response "We've been called that" -- again, carefully neither confirming nor denying, which makes sense if their nature transcends human comprehension.

Comment: In the film, one of the Bureau's members explicitly states that their goal is to get humanity to the point where it can run its own affairs without destroying itself when he tells Matt Damon that they've let humanity run its own affairs twice in its history; they created the Roman Empire, only to watch humanity destroy it, then they took us to the late 19th century, only to watch us fight two world wars and reach the Cuban Missile Crisis. After that, they took over again. This is the reason Matt Damon is deliberately set against the Bureau by "The Chairman" ('God'); he has to make a choice.

Answer (score -4):

The guys in the hats as I call them. Has to be higher power some type of god if there's a divine plan that means if somebody in charge so what they are are working angels let's call him for this higher power or God. If you go off track they reroute you and in some cases like Matt Damon's which day say they had one before it took 40 something years to get the guy back on track  and how they did it was they were just honest with him and told him the truth like they did with Damon in the beginning instead of the end and he fights it. But what they are are angels or staff whatever you want to call him employees workers anything but they work for a higher power and yes it has to be a god some sort maybe not boot up because nobody's fat.

Comment: Hmm.  I would recommend that you go through and proofread this answer.  It would also be helpful if you cited some pertinent information in the movie or original novel that supports your claims.  Cheers!